# clone immutable object in Java

Tags: java, clone, immutability

i have an immutable object that has weight as int, in my code, i need to update the weight, inroder to do that, i need to make a copy of that object and set the weight with updated value. but the object doesn't have a clone() override, and i don't know which way is better, clone() or implement Cloneable interface?

here is my class:

```
public class WeightedEdge implements Edge {

    private final WeightedEdgeComparator _weightedEdgeComparator;

    private final Vertex _target;

    private final int _weight;

    WeightedEdge(Bundle bundle, Vertex target, int weight) {
        _weightedEdgeComparator = new EdgeComparator(bundle.getDirection());
        _target = target;
        _weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public Vertex target() {
        return _target;
    }

    @Override
    public int weight() {
        return _weight;
    }

        @Override
    public int compareTo(WeightedEdge o) {
        return _EdgeComparator.compare(this, o);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {...}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) { ... }

    @Override
    public String toString() { ... }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just returning a new object with the new value:

```
// as mentioned by AndrewBissell, there is no reference to the bundle
// luckily, we only need the direction from the bundle :)
private final int _direction;

WeightedEdge(Bundle bundle, Vertex target, int weight) {
    this(bundle.getDirection(), target, weight);
}

WeightedEdge(int direction, Vertex target, int weight)
{
    _direction = direction;
    _weightedEdgeComparator = new EdgeComparator(_direction);
    _target = target;
    _weight = weight;

}

WeightedEdge updatedObject(int newWeight)
{
    return new WeightedEdge(_direction, _target, newWeight);
}
```

Comment: I think the problem with this is that the `WeightedEdge` class doesn't keep a reference to the `_bundle` in its constructor.

Comment: @AndrewBissell - you are right, I overlooked that... I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pass the `Bundle` or possibly a direction into the constructor solely for the purpose of using them to instantiate an `EdgeComparator` in the constructor, simply make the `EdgeComparator` the constructor argument, and store a reference to a cloned instance of it it in a field on `WeightedEdge`:

```
WeightedEdge(EdgeComparator comparator, Vertex target, int weight) {
    _weightedEdgeComparator = comparator.clone();
    _target = target;
    _weight = weight;
}
```

Then you can have `WeightedEdge` implement `Cloneable` and you will be able to provide all the necessary arguments when constructing the clone. This also allows you to separate your decision about `EdgeComparator` implementations from your `WeightedEdge` implementation, which is good OO practice.

Also, you need to make sure that all instances of `Vertex` are immutable or it will be possible to construct a mutable instance of this class by passing a mutable `target` into it. Alternatively, you could clone `target` in the constructor as well.

If the `EdgeComparator` is not cloneable, then there is no alternative to providing a constructor which accepts and stores a reference to the direction as shown in Binyamin Sharet's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another constructor to clone your object, and update only the weight part.

```
WeightedEdge(WeightedEdge wEdge, int weight) {
     //copy all fields of wEdge into THIS object, except weight.  
     //use int weight parameter to set the new weight
}
```

hth